# What other space vehicles were affected by cold welding?

Tags: artificial-satellite, history, probe, cold-welding

The [Wikipedia page on cold welding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_welding) states that

> Mechanical problems in early satellites were sometimes attributed to cold welding.

But only mentions Galileo as an example of spacecraft were cold welding occurred. What satellites encountered problems most likely due to cold welding?

Comment: @uhoh For Galileo, cold welding does seem to be the accepted explanation https://web.archive.org/web/20180208192609/https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19940028813.pdf https://history.nasa.gov/sp4231.pdf

Comment: ah, I see you've made an edit :-)